# Lemma 2.1.1.4 in Lurie's HTT

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

I have encountered a problem in understanding Lurie's proof of the following fact:

"Given a left fibration between simplicial sets $q:X \to S$, there exists a functor $$ho(S) \to Ho(sSet)$$ which is defined as follows: a point $s \in S$ is sent to the fiber $X_s$ of $q$ over $s$, and an arrow $f:s \to s'$ in $S'$ is sent to the homotopy class of a lift in

[image]

restricted to $\{1\} \times X_s$, which will be denoted by $f_!:X_s \to X_{s'}$".

The author wants to characterize the map $$[f_!]\circ (\cdot): Ho(sSet)(\cdot, X_s) \to Ho(sSet)(\cdot, X_{s'})$$ so as to obtain the desired result (except for the independence from the homotopy class of $f$, which I guess is left to the reader).

The problem is I don't see why it holds that, given a $K\in sSet$ and arrows $\eta:K \to X_s, \ \eta':K \to X_{s'}$, $$\eta'\simeq f_! \circ \eta \iff \exists p:K \times \Delta[1] \to X$$ such that $p_{|K \times \{0\}}\simeq \eta, \ p_{|K \times \{1\}}\simeq \eta'$ and $$q \circ p= K \times \Delta[1] \to \Delta[1] \to S$$ where the last arrow is $f$.

Thanks in advance for any help, which will of course be highly appreciated.

Comment: I want to comment that the pullback of a right horn along a left fibration is a right anodyne map. One may find this statement in Rezk's lecture notes ' Stuff about quasicategories'. But I think he/she does not provide a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the diagram

[image]

where the top left horizontal arrow is given by $\eta$. Observe that homotopy classes of lifts of the map $X_s \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow S$ are the same as homotopy classes of lifts of the map $K \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow S$. This follows from the same argument showing that the homotopy class of $f_!$ only depends on $f$, together with the fact that the left hand square is a pullback. (I'll include the argument below for completeness).

Given that, we're done. A lift of $K \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow S$ is precisely the map $p$ as stated, and the above observation says the lift is homotopic to the composition $K \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow X_s \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow X$, which is the same as saying that $[\eta'] = [f_!] \circ [\eta]$.

---

Okay, now for the promised argument which says that homotopy classes of lifts in a diagram like

[image]

only depend on the map $f$. But such a lift is equivalent to a section of $X \times_S (Y \times \Delta^1)$ over $Y \times \Delta^1$ which is specified at $Y \times \{0\}$. This pullback may be obtained by first pulling back $X$ to $\Delta^1$, where the fibration trivializes up to homotopy. Thus $X \times_S(Y \times \Delta^1)$ is trivial up to homotopy so that sections are determined up to homotopy by maps $Y \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow X_s$. Since we've already specified the map on $Y \times \{0\}$, there is only one extension up to homotopy as $Y \times \{0\} \rightarrow Y \times \Delta^1$ is an equivalence.

Comment: (Alternatively I can quote Corollary 2.1.2.9 of HTT if you don't like that argument at the end.)

Comment: First of all thanks, I just have two questions: I like the argument at the end, but it seems to me that you are using the fact that the pullback of two homotopic maps along a left fibration gives two homotopic maps. Is it true also for left fibrations (I knew it for Kan fibrations)?

Comment: Secondly, I agree that having a lift for $X_s \times \Delta[1] \to S$ gives me a lift for $K \times \Delta[1] \to S$, but how to obtain the converse in order to establish the equivalence you mentioned?

Comment: For your second question: Applying the last argument for $Y = K$ and $Y = X_s$ shows that in *both* cases the homotopy class of a lift is determined by $f$, i.e. there is only one homotopy class of lift for $K \times \Delta^1 \rightarrow S$ so it must be the one obtained by composiiton.

Comment: For the first question: I believe the exact thing I need is the aforementioned corollary or 2.1.2.10, I can try to rewrite this more clearly later.

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix everything, using 2.1.2.10, I am just missing a detail: I want $f_!$ to be independent from the homotopy class of $f$ when seen as an arrow in $\tau_1 S$. Is it true that the condition of being in the same class for arrows $f,f' \in \tau_1 S$ implies them being homotopic as maps $\Delta [1] \to S$? I just need $\Delta[1] \times \Delta[1]/ (\{ 0\} \times \Delta[1]) = \Delta[2]$

Comment: I am confused by your last sentence. Given two homotopic maps from $K\times \Delta^1$ to $X$, is it clear how to prove the induced maps from $K\times \Delta^1$ to $X_{s'}$ are homotopic?